# How can I create a pem file + google-authenticator access to Amazon EC2?

Tags: authentication, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, openssh, sshd

I'm trying to create an authentication process to a Amazon EC2 Ubuntu instance that will require the usage a key-pair generated by Amazon AND using [Google-Authenticator](https://github.com/google/google-authenticator). Ergo I want to login to the instance with my pem file and then be prompted with the verification code prompt.

```
Verification code:
```

I've managed to login to my server using my pem file. I have also managed to install Google-Authenticator successfully and use it to login with a separate user (not ubuntu) that I've created and given a specific password.

On my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` I have:

```
ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication no
UsePAM yes
AuthenticationMethods keyboard-interactive
```

and on my `/etc/pam.d/sshd`:

```
@include common-auth
auth required pam_google_authenticator.so
```

If I add `publickey` to `AuthenticationMethods` then on login I'm prompted for a password instead of using the pem file I'm providing in:

```
ssh -i my-key.pem ubuntu@*.*.*.*
```

How can I get OpenSSH to authenticate via pem file --> google-authenticator?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was to be checked by a `pem` file, a password and a verification OTP. For this I had:

In: `/etc/pam.d/sshd/`:

```
@include common-auth
auth required pam_sepermit.so
auth required pam_google_authenticator.so
```

In: `/etc/ssh/sshd_config/`:

```
AuthenticationMethods publickey,keyboard-interactive
```

The rest of the configs are as described above. Notice `publickey` comes before `keyboard-interactive` in `AuthenticationMethods`, otherwise the verification code comes first and then the pem file checking.